# Running animation and executing business logic simultaneously on uiThread?

Tags: android, android-animation

In Android, is there any way to run the animation and business logic code in UI Thread simultaneously.

I added animation to the `cardview` while user click. Whenever user click the cardview  ACTION_DOWN  event was fired.  At that time I started animation and business logic in UI Thread.

The animation looks stuttered. How to overcome this issue?

```
cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            performActionDownAnimation();
                            performBusinessLogic();
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            performActionUpAnimation();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: that depends on your code. You didn't share it.

Comment: is this possible to overcome the issue which is mentioned above? Are you expect my code?

Comment: the solution depends on your code. I don't see it. Can't help, sorry.

Comment: what `"business logic"` do you mean?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I'll share the code soon.

Comment: @pskink while doing animation I'll perform business logic(`some calculation, database operation,etc..`) in the app.

Comment: how long is it? is your `some calculation` something like `x = y * z` or you are performing long time operation that takes a second or more? if so, you have to do that in a background thread

Comment: Not like simple calculation. Execution of business logic took around 2 seconds.

Comment: so you have the answer why it looks stuttered

Comment: Yes I have the answer why it looks stuttered. But I want to overcome the issue

Comment: i already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556977/running-animation-and-executing-business-logic-simultaneously-on-uithread#comment84111773_48556977)

Comment: But I want to do some business logic operations in uiThread itself.

Comment: so your animation will stutter - you have to choose between those two - you cannot have them both